# Clementine can't play m4a files. missing plugin issue cannot be solved

Tags: plugins, clementine, m4a

Many suggest to delete `~/.gstreamer-0.10/` and install `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`.

But when I try installing `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` apt-get tells me it's installed at latest version. And when I delete `~/.gstreamer-0.10/` and try playing an m4a clementine still says that the plugin is missing and I find the `.gstreamer-0.10` there! (apparently regenerated by clementine).

My clementine is Version 1.2.3 and **not** installed from the official ubuntu repos. *(coz the network remote doesn't work with them. Nevermind.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` fixes this.

Here's a repo installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: 1 Month later, already broken: `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: really! well too bad :( try searching for an alternate source for the package.

Comment: Actually, I switched to use the [clementine-dev ppa](https://launchpad.net/~me-davidsansome/+archive/ubuntu/clementine-dev), because this fixes all of the stupid gstreamer problems by simply using gstreamer1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use dev version of Clementine, solved my problem.

ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine-dev

https://launchpad.net/~me-davidsansome/+archive/ubuntu/clementine-dev