# Clementine doesn't play m4a anymore after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, music, codecs, gstreamer, m4a

When my system was 14.04 I had this problem and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618640/clementine-cant-play-m4a-files-missing-plugin-issue-cannot-be-solved/699602#699602) fixed it.

Now I upgraded the system to 16.04, I didn't find clementine so I installed it. It couldn't play m4a files so I found my old solution and tried it. But it still can't play m4a.

Then now I tried upgrading to the dev version of clementine (the other answer) but still no luck. I keep getting the gstreamer error.

How do I get m4a files to work in 16.04?

*I have a 14.04 clone of my system with clementine on it playing m4a.*

**Edit:**

`apt-cache search gstreamer.*bad`

```
gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 - GObject introspection data for the GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set
gnome-video-effects-extra - GNOME Video Effects - extra plugins
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set (debug symbols)
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc - GStreamer documentation for plugins from the "bad" set
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad - GStreamer faad plugin from the "bad" set
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers - GStreamer videoparsers plugin from the "bad" set
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
sound-juicer - GNOME CD Ripper
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set (Multiverse Variant)
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 - GStreamer shared libraries from the "bad" set
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

`sudo find ~/ -mount -name \*gstreamer\*`

```
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1+srt5_amd64
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1+srt5_amd64.md5
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1+srt5_amd64
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1+srt5_amd64.md5
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/rw/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/doc/libgstreamer0.10-0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/doc/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.30.0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer0.10
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer0.10/gstreamer-0.10
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1+srt5_i386.md5
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1+srt5_i386
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1+srt5_i386.md5
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1+srt5_i386
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/rw/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/gstreamer-0.10.mo
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/doc/libgstreamer0.10-0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/doc/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.30.0
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer0.10
/home/mina/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer0.10/gstreamer-0.10
/home/mina/.local/share/gstreamer-1.0
/home/mina/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/winegstreamer.dll
/home/mina/.wine/drive_c/windows/syswow64/winegstreamer.dll
/home/mina/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
/home/mina/.cache/software-center/icons/gstreamer0.10-fluendo-plugins-icon-gstreamer0.10-fluendo-plugins.png
/home/mina/.cache/software-center/icons/gstreamer0.10-fluendo-plugins-wmv-icon-gstreamer0.10-fluendo-plugins-wmv.png
```

as for `apt list --installed` here's a [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24016872/). One of the longest outputs ever hehe X)

*Note: if you think my system is a mess, yes I know (unfortunately).*

---

**Edit 2:** Ran clementine in the terminal. Here's part of the startup output:

```
04:12:14.255 INFO  main:329                         Clementine 1.3.1-284-g8a6cc8b 
04:12:14.419 DEBUG NetworkProxyFactory:49           Detected system proxy URLs: ("", "", "", "") 
04:12:14.421 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_536547441" 
04:12:14.423 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_1160234507" 
04:12:14.425 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_498140324" 
04:12:14.428 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_2096635439" 
04:12:14.430 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_878615057" 
04:12:14.432 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_536547441" 
04:12:14.433 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_1273687375" 
04:12:14.434 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_546149030" 
04:12:14.437 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:281      Starting worker 0x7fedb79fa660 "/usr/bin/clementine-tagreader" "/tmp/clementine_884135863" 
04:12:14.438 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_2096635439" 
04:12:14.438 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_1160234507" 
04:12:14.438 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_498140324" 
04:12:14.440 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda800c540 connected to "/tmp/clementine_536547441" 
04:12:14.440 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda800daf0 connected to "/tmp/clementine_1160234507" 
04:12:14.440 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda800c5c0 connected to "/tmp/clementine_498140324" 
04:12:14.440 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda8010420 connected to "/tmp/clementine_2096635439" 
04:12:14.441 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_878615057" 
04:12:14.441 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda8011a00 connected to "/tmp/clementine_878615057" 
04:12:14.446 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_1273687375" 
04:12:14.446 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda800ec80 connected to "/tmp/clementine_1273687375" 
04:12:14.446 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_546149030" 
04:12:14.447 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda80145b0 connected to "/tmp/clementine_546149030" 
04:12:14.453 INFO  main:48                          TagReader worker connecting to "/tmp/clementine_884135863" 
04:12:14.453 DEBUG WorkerPool<HandlerType>:301      Worker 0x7feda8012520 connected to "/tmp/clementine_884135863" 
04:12:14.490 DEBUG GnomeGlobalShortcutBackend:52    registering 
04:12:14.610 DEBUG MainWindow:226                   Starting 
04:12:14.633 WARN  unknown                          QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2 
04:12:14.666 DEBUG CoverProviders:35                Registered cover provider "Amazon" 
04:12:14.667 DEBUG CoverProviders:35                Registered cover provider "MusicBrainz" 
04:12:14.667 DEBUG CoverProviders:35                Registered cover provider "last.fm" 
04:12:14.677 DEBUG MainWindow:297                   Initialising player 
04:12:14.686 DEBUG MainWindow:303                   Creating models 
04:12:14.703 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "classicalradio" 
04:12:14.703 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "ClassicalRadio" 
04:12:14.704 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "di" 
04:12:14.704 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "DigitallyImported" 
04:12:14.717 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Icecast" 
04:12:14.722 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Jamendo" 
04:12:14.727 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "jazzradio" 
04:12:14.727 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "JazzRadio" 
04:12:14.728 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "magnatune" 
04:12:14.732 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Magnatune" 
04:12:14.737 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Podcasts" 
04:12:14.741 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "rockradio" 
04:12:14.741 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "RockRadio" 
04:12:14.745 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "SavedRadio" 
04:12:14.749 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "radiotunes" 
04:12:14.749 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "RadioTunes" 
04:12:14.753 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "somafm" 
04:12:14.753 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "SomaFM" 
04:12:14.757 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "intergalacticfm" 
04:12:14.757 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Intergalactic FM" 
04:12:14.765 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "SoundCloud" 
04:12:14.766 DEBUG SpotifyService:108               Spotify system blob path: "/usr/bin/clementine-spotifyblob" 
04:12:14.766 DEBUG SpotifyService:109               Spotify local blob path: "/home/mina/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version16-64bit/blob" 
04:12:14.770 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Spotify" 
04:12:14.770 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "subsonic" 
04:12:14.792 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Subsonic" 
04:12:14.815 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "box" 
04:12:14.815 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Box" 
04:12:14.819 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "dropbox" 
04:12:14.819 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Dropbox" 
04:12:14.823 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "googledrive" 
04:12:14.823 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Google Drive" 
04:12:14.827 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "seafile" 
04:12:14.827 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "Seafile" 
04:12:14.831 INFO  Player:627                       Registered URL handler for "skydrive" 
04:12:14.831 DEBUG InternetModel:131                Adding internet service: "OneDrive" 
04:12:14.834 WARN  DeviceKitLister:55               Error enumerating DeviceKit-disks devices: "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown" "The name org.freedesktop.UDisks was not provided by any .service files" 
04:12:14.837 DEBUG MainWindow:322                   Creating UI 
04:12:14.889 DEBUG MainWindow:867                   Creating equalizer 
04:12:14.891 DEBUG MainWindow:896                   Creating now playing widget 
04:12:14.915 DEBUG _MessageReplyBase:24             Waiting on ID 0
```

...then it keeps on scanning my files.

When I try to run an m4a file here's the output

```
04:12:57.114 DEBUG PlaylistBackend:294              Saving playlist 196 
04:12:57.123 DEBUG PlaylistBackend:294              Saving playlist 46 
04:12:57.126 DEBUG {anonymous}:42                   QDBusError("", "") 
04:12:57.362 DEBUG GnomeGlobalShortcutBackend:96    registered 
04:12:57.435 DEBUG {anonymous}:78                   Remote interface published on Avahi: QDBusError("", "") 
04:13:42.355 DEBUG Database:584                     Starting database integrity check 
04:13:42.357 DEBUG Database:645                     Starting database backup 
04:13:54.113 DEBUG _MessageReplyBase:24             Waiting on ID 406 
04:13:54.113 DEBUG TagReader:984                    Loading art from "/path/bla/bla/name.m4a" 
04:13:54.114 INFO  MoodbarLoader:147                Creating moodbar data for "/path/bla/bla/name.m4a" 
04:13:54.115 DEBUG MessageReply<MessageType>:90     Releasing ID 406 (finished) 
04:13:54.115 DEBUG _MessageReplyBase:26             Acquired ID 406 
04:13:54.115 DEBUG PlaylistBackend:294              Saving playlist 183 
04:13:54.129 ERROR MoodbarPipeline:133              Error processing  QUrl( "file:///path/bla/bla/name.m4a" )  : "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in." 
04:13:54.129 ERROR MoodbarPipeline:133              Error processing  QUrl( "file:///path/bla/bla/name.m4a" )  : "GStreamer encountered a general stream error." 
04:13:54.138 ERROR GstEnginePipeline:645            1 "gsturidecodebin.c(1006): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin-0:
no suitable plugins found:
gstdecodebin2.c(4565): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin-0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin1:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: Apple Lossless Audio (ALAC) (audio/x-alac, codec_data=(buffer)00000024616c616300000000000010000010280a0e0200ff00002f5a000bcdeb0000ac44, samplesize=(int)16, max-input-size=(int)12142, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2)
" 
04:13:54.138 ERROR GstEnginePipeline:645            1 "qtdemux.c(5520): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin-0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin1/GstQTDemux:qtdemux1:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked" 
04:13:54.165 DEBUG MainWindow:1484                  position 0 scrobble point 187 status 0 
04:14:03.325 WARN  GstEngine:693                    Gstreamer error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in." 
04:14:03.325 ERROR logging:56                       Source ID 69 was not found when attempting to remove it 
04:14:03.327 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running 
04:14:12.458 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running 
04:14:21.731 WARN  OSD:140                          Error sending notification "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply"
```

**Edit 3:**

`apt-cache search gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`

```
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set (Multiverse Variant)
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in` @L.D.James

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I was having problems reproducing errors because it was working on all my machines.  I finally created a new install instance to check.  There's a response to your comment in the answer.  The requested output there will provide the difference between your install and a default Ubuntu install, of which I'll be able to point out the changes you'll have to make to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to take a guess that your .m4a are alac which would be decoded by `gstreamer1.0-libav`.

Atm that plugin is broken in 16.04, I reported & a fix has been done but not yet released. You can get the new package fom the -proposed repo or wait a bit for it to make the main repos.

Bug for reference - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-libav1.0/+bug/1661842

The new package version  is 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 After updating if clementine is open it must be closed, then re-opened to use the new plugin.

Comment: will if I'll get the update in a few days I'll wait. I've added an extra output that might be useful

Comment: That just shows it's alac & as mentioned new package will fix.  Maybe it will show next week, otherwise instead of enabling -proposed just go here, pick arch to download the .deb. https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/universe/proposed/gstreamer1.0-libav   Then install the downloaded .deb with apt, example here with 64 bit, downloaded to ~/Downloads, `sudo apt install ./Downloads/gstreamer1.0-libav_1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: This worked like a charm for me with Clementine 1.3.1 on Kubuntu 18.10 while trying to play .mp4 files that were copied from a computer running macOS. I guess the files must have been formatted as apple lossless and clementine was freaking out because i didnt have the `gstreamer1.0-libav` package installed

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted (as I'm sure you know) is for an older version of the gstreamer.

Using the default repository will be more likely to survive Ubuntu version upgrades.

You'll have to install the full updated gstreamer package:

```
$ sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

---

Remove the previously installed cached version by deleting ~/.local/share/Steam.

**Note to (Valve's) Steam gamers, you probably don't want to remove this folder, Steam has all its configurations in it. You may need to relocate your steam library.**

Command to delete:

```
$ rm ~/.local/share/Steam
```

You may have to exit Clementine for the change to take effect.

Comment: I was using the default repo when I was 14.04. It was removed on upgrade, then I installed the default, then I installed the dev. Anyway when I try to install `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` it says I have it in the newest version

Comment: @MinaMichael  Sorry, I was looking at the PPA in the link in your message.  You mentioned in your message that **old solution**.  The older solution will not work in 16.04.  It's mostly the culprit of your problem.  There's no reference that you used the system's default repository out side the PPA.  Will you show the output of these commands? **(1)** `apt list --installed`; **(2)** `apt-cache search gstreamer.*bad`; **(3)** `sudo find ~/ -mount -name \*gstreamer\*`?  Add the output to [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/883732/edit) to make it easier to see the culprit.

Comment: added outputs. Note that now my clementine is from the dev repo (which is mentioned in the old question). `Version 1.3.1-284-g8a6cc8b`. Thank you for your concern. Tell me if you need any other output. Debugging is a hobby

Comment: @MinaMichael The output is sufficient.  I ammended the answer with the culprit.  And no, I don't your system is messed up.  We all develop little glitches from time to time.  But the resolution is usually a simple matter.  Thanks in advance if you will let me know if this resolves the issue.  I have a test machine on the bench that I'll use for something else when your issues is resolved.

Comment: removed the folder *(backed it up somewhere away)* and restarted clementine but no luck. Worth noting that clementine takes too much time to start. Longer than before

Comment: added another output that I think is useful

Comment: The output of this will be useful.  Also, if I were you I'd hold off on installing` PPA's` for now and try to use the default from the default repository which in this case works since 16.04.  Can you give the output of: `apt-cache search gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`?

Comment: added output. How do I roll back? I think I should do `sudo apt purge clementine` then I need to remove the dev ppa (plz tell me how. didn't remove much PPAs before) then reinstall. right?

Comment: You'll have to remove the previous installed `PPA` version.  Run this: `sudo apt remove --purge gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`.  After this you may have to remove the cache again.  I was already typing in the resolution of removing the PPA when your message came in.  I'm sure this will resolve the issue.

Comment: did `sudo apt remove --purge gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` then removed `~/.local/share/Steam` again. restarted clementine. still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53836/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-mina-michael).

Comment: It turns out that the problem was with `gstreamer1.0-libav`. Thank you for  your effort :)